# White banding/artifacts on Seaborn/Matplotlib barplots within FacetGrid/subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting a column subplot of approximate probability distributions with Seaborn. I have a frustrating issue where each barplot has these white bars as seen in the image below. I have turned all axis labels off, played with line-widths and figures sizes (int sizes) but I cant for the life of me find how to get of this.

my code is of the form:

```
import seaborn as sns 

fig = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="Category",height=2, aspect=4, row_order=category_order,
    margin_titles=True);

fig.map(sns.barplot, "value", "frequency", color="b",order=bar_order,lw=1);

fig.set(yticks=[]);
fig.set(ylabel='');
fig.set(xticks=[]);
fig.set(xlabel='');

fig.savefig('output.png',dpi=300)
```

[image: Bar Plots]

I thought this was an issue with figure width being a float, or with the axis labels but I cant figure it out. There are <30 bars per chart which, but around 20 subplots in total.

**As a secondary question:**

Is there any means to rotate the row label to horizontal rather than vertical for a sns.FacetGrid type subplot? Not the axis labels but the label of the row its self in the FacetGrid/subplot grid which is turned on with `margin_titles=True`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a toy dataset (refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))